# UI-router: nested state resolving

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two states: a 'contacts' and a 'contacts.all' which is a child state of the previuos. I want this child state to pre-load data from server:

```
.state('contacts', {
    url: "/contacts",
    controller: 'ContactsCtrl'
})
.state('contacts.all', {
    url: "/all",
    resolve: {
        initialContacts: function (contactsCRUD) {
            return contactsCRUD.getAll().$promise;
        }
    }
})
```

and then inject the to the ContactsCtrl controller:

```
function ContactsCtrl($scope, initialContacts) {
    $scope.Contacts = initialContacts || {};
}
```

I do need these data preloaded only in the 'contacts.all', not 'contacts' state. If I leave this code as is and try to navigate any of these states then I'll get an inject error saying "unknown provider" for the "initialContacts" because the controller seems to be instantiated before the initialContacts is known.
What is normal way to do it? I know I can add a "resolve" option to the parent state and set initialContacts to something like {} but I dont think it's a good practice.

Comment: Move `controller: 'ContactsCtrl'` to the **'contacts.all'** state

Comment: @AlonEitan but I want to use same controller for these two and a coulpe other states. Contacts - load all, load one, edit one, save one etc.

Comment: Oh, so I think you need to use a default `resolve` with resolves `initialContacts` to _null_ in the parent state, don't think there's other way

Comment: Or - Inject `$injector` to the controller instead of `initialContacts`, then check `if( $injector.has('initialContacts') ) { $scope.Contacts = $injector.get('initialContacts'); }`

Comment: @AlonEitan it returns "false". Probably because tere is no "initialContacts" parameter in the controller (because if I put it there then this will return error described in the topic).

Comment: Have you wrapped `initialContacts` inside **' '** ?

Comment: @AlonEitan yes I did...